# How to host Python functions on Firebase (Google) Cloud functions?

Tags: python, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, cloud

So I have python code used for processing some text. My objective is to link this with my flutter app, which I planned as the input interface for the code. As planned, the flutter app will take a text input, use it as the input to the Python functions, then take the output from there and send it back to the app. But I really can't find any clear sources on how to go about this. Would really appreciate some help. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python

Comment: I would make this the answer @DougStevenson. It's the right one. :)

Comment: Thanks @Doug Stevenson. I would make it the answer too if I could. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions is a serverless execution environment for building and connecting cloud services. With Cloud Functions you write simple, single-purpose functions that are attached to events emitted from your cloud infrastructure and services. Your function is triggered when an event being watched is fired.

This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python) shows you how to create and deploy a Python Cloud Function using the Cloud Console.